# jqGrid Issue when trying to use pager

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid, I just started doing samples on jqGrid in asp.net web forms. I used the array method for sample purpose with out any extra features. Now I am trying to add the pager feature to the jqGrid. While adding the pager feature i am getting the following error.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property
>   'integer': object is null or undefined

error is coming at the following part of the plugin

```
k=b.jgrid.formatter.integer||{}
```

I am providing you with the code snippet that I have done till now.

**Aspx Page**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SmjqGrid" runat="server" >
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jQuery.1.9.1.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"  />
            <%--<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" />--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/ui.multiselect.js"  />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                height: 250,
                colNames: [ 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total'],
                colModel: [
        { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
        { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
        { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" }
    ],
                multiselect: true,
                caption: "Sample On jqGrid",
                rowNum: 5,
                pager: '#pager'
            });
            var mydata = [
        { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
        { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
        { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
        { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
        { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
        { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
        { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
        { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
        { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
        ];
            for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
                jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <table id="list4"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
```

Hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include `grid.locale-en.js` (you commented the corresponding line in your code). It needed be included before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file))

Comment: Oleg, Can you tell me why we need to include the locale file

Comment: @Rohith: If you examine files `grid.locale-XX.js` you could answer yourself on the question. Integer 1000 can be displays as `1,000` or `1.000` or `1 000` in different countries. So one defined the information in separate file. Some products includes EN-US information in the main JavaScript file, but you need *replace* language specific information by including language file *after* the main  JavaScript file. jqGrid follow another rule: it don't contain any language specific information. So you have to include alwasy **two** files: some `grid.locale-XX.js` and then `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I know that people still use jqGrid :)

So, nothing I found online helped. The only thing that did help and I can find no reason behind, is that this error is not happening and the pager is working fine only when using the minified jqGrid script... (meaning replacing the jqgrid.src.js with jqgrid.min.js). I don't know why it helped - possible because the page I'm currently working on is running about 20 different scripts, so maybe there's some sort of clashing problem.